# GLU.dll not found

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

When I run my project in Release mode, I have the following error:
  `This application has failed to start because GLU.dll was not found.`
Besides, when I run in Debug mode it only works when I'm running through Visual Studio because if I run the .exe file, it doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger creates the process with an initial working directory that is not the directory where the executable resides. By default the debugger uses the project directory as the working directory for the debuggee. So, I suspect that your DLL has been placed in the project directory. And the DLL is successfully located by the loader by dint of being in the working directory.

Now, when you run the executable by double-clicking on it, the working directory is the directory in which the executable lives. And so the DLL is not found.

You should not rely on the working directory for DLL resolution. Best practise is to put your DLLs in the same directory as your executable. Once you do that you will find that your application loads. The cleanest way to arrange this is to use a post-build event to copy the DLL from the project directory to the executable output directory.